# MySQL music database

Tags: mysql

I am creating a MySQL database of music under Creative Commons. I am new to MySQL, however, so I am not sure if this is the correct setup, and if it is, how to query it.
Here are my tables:

```
 - `artist`
   - `id` - artist id
   - `name` - artist name
 - `genre`
   - ` id ` - genre id
   - ` name ` - genre name
 - `license`
   - `id` - license id
   - `name` - license name
 - `song`
   - `id` - song id
   - `artist ` - artist id
   - `title` - song title
   - `license ` - license id
   - `link` - link to song
 - `songgenre`
   - `genre` - genre id
   - `song` - song id
```

I would like it to give me this information:

```
------------------------------------------------
|artist | song title| genre(s)| license | link |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: An example for the genres would be:

```
-------------------------
| classical, orchestral |
-------------------------
```

Basically a list of all genres the song falls under.

Comment: select join may solve your problem

Comment: DB structure is looking good so far. As far as how to query it, it's probably best to spend some time to get familiar with MySQL on your own. Maybe try walking through this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: Kudos on the nice table design.  How do you want it displayed with the genre's?  Can you give a sample desired output with multiple genres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up piecing together the code after reading many other Stack Overflow answers and W3 Schools.
Here is the code:

```
SELECT song.id, artist.name, song.title, genre.name, license.name, song.url
FROM songs 
INNER JOIN artist ON artist.id=song.artist
INNER JOIN license ON license.id = song.license
INNER JOIN songgenre r ON song.id = r.song_id
INNER JOIN genres ON r.genre_id = genres.id
```

This gives me a result of:

```
---------------------------------------------------
|id|artist_title|title|genre_name|license_name|url|
---------------------------------------------------
|1 | Artist     |Song1| Genre1   | License   |url|
---------------------------------------------------
|1 | Same Artist|Song1| Genre2   | License   | url|
---------------------------------------------------
```

I will update the answer if I figure out how to put both genres in the same line.